# Incompatible Compliance level

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat, intellij-idea

My spring project builds successfully when I build using intellij maven window to build it. But when I configure it to deploy in tomcat server(by setting run configurations in intellij) it gives an error as follows.

```
Compliance level '1.4' is incompatible with target level '1.7'. A compliance level '1.7' or better is required
```

My maven pom.xml defines compiler plugin as follows.

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

and my pc's JAVA_HOME is pointed to jdk 1.7 
What is this error means. How to change compliance level 1.4 to 1.7
This application works well when I manually deploy it to tomcat server

Comment: What version of tomcat?